# Axios sending empty body if the json data is big

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, axios, centos8

Everything was working perfectly  After updating the repo (yum update repo) I am receiving an empty payload if the JSON size is big.
I am using Axios with Vue js and on the backend, I am using laravel. If I send the below JSON data I am getting it on the backend

```
{"id":"6162ad44a75f185dfd3d6c26","NewimageUrl":"","pos_id":"wrwerew","hasProperties":false,"is_vissible":true,"is_modifier":false,"is_combo":false,"outlet_id":"234","name":{"en":"rar","ar":null},"vendorEntityId":"wrwerew","vendorEntityId_old":"c9cb9bd0d234a93f0724f40e4c412ac2","description":{"en":"ewrewr","ar":null},"imageUrl":"public/images/outlets/234/catalogues/6162ad5e31a7f.jpeg","modifiersGroups":[],"tags":[{"text":"non-veg","tiClasses":["ti-valid"]}],"setUps":[],"nutritionInfo":{"calorieCount":0},"prices":[{"service":"delivery","price":0}],"charges":[]}
```

If I send a big JSON body. I am receiving an empty body on the backend.

```
[]
```

if I check in request header and body I can see payload and header set to JSON.
Below is the requested screenshot [request screen short](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEVjk.png)

Below is my code

```
var vue = this;
  console.log(vue.newCatalogue);
  let data=JSON.stringify(vue.newCatalogue);
       vue.axios
    .post("post-edit-catalogue",data)
    .then(function (response) {
      vue.message.type = response.data.type;
      vue.message.message = response.data.messsage;

      setTimeout(function () {}, 1000); // vue.newCatalogue.is_vissible=false;
             })
    .catch(function (error) {
      // handle error
      vue.message.type = "alert alert-danger";
      vue.message.message = error.response.data.messsage;
    })
    .finally(function () {
      // always executed
    });
```

What could be the reason? It starts happening after updating the centos 8 repo. The same code on localhost is working perfectly.

Comment: if send this following body I am getting empty.

Comment: is it posible that your php.ini was overwritten ? how big is the json that results in an empty body ?

Comment: What are the possible php.ini setting that I need to reset if that is the reason?
if you click on below link you will find json body i am trying to send
https://jsoneditoronline.org/#left=cloud.258f19ffc5684eb39812b3acc023bd96

Comment: any one can help me with this.?

Comment: @willi you were right.i change following setting and it worked for me.max_input_nesting_level 200
max_input_time 120 
max_input_vars 200